# Call function on window resize within jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, methods, window-resize

I've created a tiny jquery-method to center an element vertically and horizontally:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.center = function() {
            $(this).css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() / 2) - $(this).outerWidth(true) / 2,
                top: ($(window).height() / 2) - $(this).outerHeight(true) / 2
            });

            return this;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Now I'm able to center a specific element:

```
$('div').center();
```

As far as that everything works perfectly. But now i'd like to re-center the element on `window.resize`.

Of course, I could just call the method like this:

```
$(function onresize(){
    $('div').center(); 
    $(window).on('resize', onresize);
});
```

But i do **not** want it like this. I would like to manage this within the method (so that i can call the method normally - like in the second code-area of my question).

I've tried the following:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.center = function() {

        $( window ).resize(function() {
            $(this).css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() / 2) - $(this).outerWidth(true) / 2,
                top: ($(window).height() / 2) - $(this).outerHeight(true) / 2
            });
        });

        return this;

    }
}(jQuery));
```

But this doesn't work. Why? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You still need to run the `$.fn.center` function to register the handler. From your snippet, the $(window).resize() bit is not called.

Comment: I think `return this;` is in the wrong place. It should be after `});`. Can you please check?

Comment: @Spokey I've changed it, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @scenario Is there no way to manage this within my `$.fn.center`-function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now it hit me. The scope is not right anymore. Change it to the following

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.center = function() {
        $this = $(this);

        $( window ).resize(function() {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() / 2) - $this.outerWidth(true) / 2,
                top: ($(window).height() / 2) - $this.outerHeight(true) / 2
            });
        });

        return this;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I've totally forgot about this. But this also doesn't solve my problem completely: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/leo/fg26g/)

Comment: Thanks, that works fine! :) Sorry for my clumsiness.